# Best way to execute java program on server

Tags: java, web, server

I need to execute a java simulation program for a very long time, many hours or maybe days, and i wish i could do it on a server.
I've been heard about Cloud Computing, and i'm searching a free platform, or a very cheap one.

For example, i found [Oracle Cloud](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/java/getting-started-java-accs/getting-started-java-accs.html), but i am open to **any** type of solution.

On the link there are several points to follow to deploy an application, it seems a bit complicated and you also have to install Maven.

Do you think there is a simpler solution, or that this one could be my best try?

I mean, my program consists on a few .class files, i wish i could edit/compile/run the main class very easily, like with a kind of shell or cmd.
Unfortunately, i know very little about web programming, so i don't know even if this would be possible.

However, assuming i can launch my program, and log in after a very long time, will i be able to read the results?
Or is it possible to write a text file to read the results later?

Comment: Will your main run indefinitely, or you have to run your program in definite intervals?

Comment: Also, I would suggest AWS-Beanstalk to deploy your app (using Tomcat)

Comment: @Sridhar My main method will run indefinetily, until all calculations are done, i don't need any time of timer or scheduling

Comment: Good. You can use any server (physical/cloud) running linux. You can compile your program as a runnable jar & run the jar in background. Like, `java -jar my_app.jar [parameters] &`

Comment: Also, you can use screen configurations, to create a new screen, run your jar, disconnect it, and can resume anytime to see progress.

Comment: Else, you can use apache-tomcat, if you want a web application setup, and deploy it (But, I don't think this is required. Since, you only need it for calculations).

Comment: @Sridhar "You can compile your program as a runnable jar & run the jar in background. Like, java -jar my_app.jar [parameters]". This seems promising. Could you please link a good tutorial or any platfrom from where you would start? I'm very new to this world, and i am so confused about where should i go :D

Comment: Use an IDE like eclipse. Create a new Java project, I suggest to use `maven` or `gradle` for dependency resolving (But, you can do it manually as well, with little pain :D). Then compile & export your project as runnable jar and select your class containing `main()` as `LaunchConfiguration`. Voila! your jar is ready to run.

Comment: For reference on eclipse https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?nav=%2F1

Comment: @Sridhar Well, i was not clear, i know how to create a jar file, i meant, once you have your jar file which online platform you would choose, to " to create a new screen, run your jar, disconnect it, and can resume anytime to see progress".

Comment: Any linux platform would be able to do it. Even your local machine with linux can do it. [reference](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i wish i could do it on a server. I've been heard about Cloud Computing

A possible solution is using [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html). You only provide your Java code in a ZIP file and it will run in a "server-less" environment. What this means is that you don't have to setup a server yourself instead AWS will manage everything for you.

> i'm searching a free platform, or a very cheap one.

It's not for free, but it's pretty cheap though: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

> However, assuming i can launch my program, and log in after a very long time, will i be able to read the results? Or is it possible to write a text file to read the results later?

I would not recommend writing it to a text file, instead look at solutions such as [S3 Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) or Elasticsearch with Kibana

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a look!

Comment: Do you think that execution time (since seconds are calculated to pay) will be comparable to a jvm running on a "normal" laptop, or it will take much more time?

Comment: @AeternaAedes I think the lamba will be faster because your laptop will run a lot of other stuff as well which'll cost resources and the lambda probably scales to your needs

Comment: @AeternaAedes When I was learning about lambda these series helped me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSUEk6iMW88 keep in mind that the UI of the lambda interface has changed so some features used in the videos are located somewhere else now